# Как можно вывести данные из динамического объекта

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4, angular5

Есть следующий объект:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Батарея",
    "sections": {
      "Ємність": "2",
      "Тип": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Процесор",
    "sections": {
      "Кількість ядер": "22",
      "Назва процесора": "33",
      "Частота": "11"
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Екран",
    "sections": {
      "Тип матриці": "222",
      "Діагональ екрану": "111"
    }
  }
]
```

Как я могу достать из него данные в виде:

**Title: (Батарея)**

key ------------------------> value :

емкость -------------> 2

тип -----------------> 1

**Title 2: (Процесор)**

key ------------------------> value

**Title 3: (Екран)**

key ------------------------> value

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of product.productSection">
   <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
   <div *ngFor="let val of item.sections| keyvalue">
      <em>{{val.key}}</em> --------------> <em>{{val.value}}</em>
   </div>
</div>
```